# Multiple ng-options set default option select not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I´m having an issue with to select a default value on a select with Angular.
If my select options only has one value it´s ok and works fine

```
<select id="customerId"
        ng-model="customer"
        ng-options="customer.id  for customer in customersSelect">
</select>
```

In my angular js:

```
 $scope.customer = customer;
```

But if I try with multiple elements on `ng-options` and I set the default option, is not working

```
<select id="customerId"
        ng-model="customer"
        ng-options="customer.id as customer.name for customer in customersSelect">
</select>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845210/setting-selected-values-for-ng-options-bound-select-elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `option` tag.like below:

```
   <select 
        id="customerId"
        ng-model="customer"
        ng-options="customer.id as customer.name for customer in customersSelect">
       <option value="">PLease select one</option>
</select>
```

Thats it.