# Prepopulate Dropdown with Object

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a dropdown and want to prepopulate it with object.

```
<script>
angular.module("myapp", [])
  .controller("MyController", function($scope) {      
    $scope.country = {
        id: "2",
      name: "USA"
    };

    $scope.countries = [{
      id: "1",
      name: "India"
    }, {
      id: "2",
      name: "USA"
    }, {
      id: "3",
      name: "UK"
    }, {
      id: "4",
      name: "Nepal"
    }];
  });
</script>

<div>
  Country Name :
  <select ng-model="country" ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries"></select>
</div>
```

But the countries dropdown is not being prepopulated with country object.I am not sure what is the problem.

JSFIDDLE link :http://jsfiddle.net/6qo3vs6c/

Comment: Did you mean default value of `ng-options`? If this is what you looking for, see more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845210/setting-selected-values-for-ng-options-bound-select-elements).

Comment: I want the default value from separate object...how can I do that??

Comment: use your fiddle properly. no issues with code. http://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/6qo3vs6c/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `country as` and add `track by country.id` in `ng-options`.

```
<select ng-model="country" ng-options="country.name for country in countries track by country.id"></select>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DieuNQ/3gtvpa77/1/) is your. See [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845210/setting-selected-values-for-ng-options-bound-select-elements).

Hope this helps.